# Значение и происхождение выражения "за здорово живешь"

Tags: фразеология

Выражение ***за здорово живешь*** применяется в различных ситуациях и, вероятно, с разными оттенками значений, например:

"*А этот громила рядом с ним... Такой **за здорово живешь** переломит человеку хребет и не поморщится.*

Какой смысл может иметь этот оборот в разных случаях и каково его дословное значение?

Answer (score 3):

Ну, вот у Б.Васильева явно фразеологизм в значении **"бесплатно, безвозмездно"**.*Глядел на компас и не слышал ничего, потому что завтра должен был компас этот бесценный отдать* *за здорово живёшь*. Б.Васильев. Не стреляйте в белых лебедей.

А у Мамина-Сибиряка в значении "без всякой причины, ни  за что ни про что". *Прогнать его так, за здорово живёшь, как будто и совестно, а держать без всякого дела на своей шее  - начётисто.* М.- Сибиряк. В последний раз.

У Шишкова тоже значение "не зря": *И недаром, не зря, не "здорово живёшь" всколыхнулись его думы: Анфиса дни и ночи думала о нём.* Угрюм-река.

У Абрамова в значении "напрасно, бесцельно, без всякой надобности": *А ты думаешь, в комсомол за здорово живёшь приняли?*

Если говорить о дословном значении, нужно заметить, что здор**о**во -  это  наречие в значении "хорошо, благополучно", ведь праславянское *sъdorvъ образовано из приставки с, равной по значению su (хороший), и  основы 
dorvъ (дерево, дуб). Прилагательное здоровый первоначально имело смысл "прочный, крепкий, как дуб", потом стало "сильный, крепкий", а потом - "невредимый".На вост.-слав. почве после падения слаб. гласных ъ произошло озвончение глухого **с** в **з** перед звонким **д** .

Поэтому в приветствии не только пожелание здоровья, но и всего хорошего, благополучия во всём. А настоящее время употреблено вместо повелительного наклонения, видимо,  как фигура речи, чтобы прозвучало как бы беспрекословное, категорическое, вот как в повелении: "Теперь все слушают!"

Answer (score 1):

> [Здорово живешь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE) (живете)! ( прост.) — приветствие при встрече.
>
> [Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка](https://phraseology.academic.ru/4083/%D0%97%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%88%D1%8C_%28%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%91%D1%82%D0%B5%29)
> Здорово живёшь (живёте)
> Толкование
> Здорово живёшь (живёте)ЗДОРО́ВО ЖИВЁШЬ (ЖИВЁТЕ). Прост. В речевом этикете: приветствие при встрече; здравствуй. — Здорово живёшь, соседка, — поздоровался Петра, касаясь рукавицей шапки (Шолохов. Тихий Дон). — Здорово живёте, бабоньки! — сказал мужчина, сняв фуражку и поклонившись налево, где около одного дома разговаривали шесть женщин (Ф. Решетников. Глумовы).

Вспоминается "Здоровеньки булы!" Тарапуньки и Штепселя.

Фактически это пожелание здоровья.

Осмелюсь предположить, что "за здорово живешь" означает *легко и/или без особого повода и/или не требуя оплаты* (всего лишь за пожелание здоровья или ради такового).

Comment: А может ли значения оборота быть неясным, как в приведенном мною предложении?  О чем там говорится: нанести вред без причины (неадекватное поведение)  или сделать это легко, без особых усилий,что свидетельствует о хорошей физической форме человека?

Comment: Мне кажется, значение "легко" объединяет все оттенки - ни с того ни с сего, беспричинно, бесцельно, без усилий.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что на прямой вопрос есть прямой ответ.
**За "здорово живешь" - ни за что, за пожелание здоровья. Аналогично "За спасибо".**
Не стал бы и писать, настолько тут все очевидно, но вот Людмила ссылается на Шишкова...
И там вроде как другое значение просматривается. Вот тут я не очень согласен. Там ведь не просто "без причины" - а именно отсутствие вины, то есть деяния, за которое пришлось заплатить некую цену, или цену, несоразмерную деянию. А это уже максимально близко к значению "бесплатно", тому что у Васильева.
То я есть я полагаю, что и в этом случае значение принципиально не разнится с современным "за так". 
(+)
Я взял примеры от Людмилы и вижу, что в них во всех значение если и не полностью, в большой степени синонимично "(за) просто так", "за спасибо", "за красивые глаза".

**Прогнать его так, за [просто так], как будто и совестно, а держать без всякого дела на своей шее - начётисто.**

**И недаром, не зря, не "здорово живёшь" всколыхнулись его думы: Анфиса дни и ночи думала о нём.**  Здесь вообще "недаром" в авторском ряду. Зачем надо подчеркивать значение "не зря", противопоставляя его этому "недаром" - не вижу.

**А ты думаешь, в комсомол за [красивые глаза] приняли?** - тут вообще это значение первое на ум приходит, никаких "без причины" не просматривается.

Короче везде я вижу смысл не только отсутствующей причины, но в первую очередь именно отсутствие именно некоего обменного эквивалента, если не материального, то морального,  логического.

Comment: Здесь по крайней мере два значения: 1)  получить/ причинить благо или вред  без видимой причины; 2) сделать что-то легко, не затрачивая особых усилий. Например: За здорово живешь сохатый не дастся, волки это понимали и теперь уравнивали силы.

Comment: Уважаемый behemothus, не согласна с Вами, В "Угрюм-реке" автор поставил фразеологизм в однородный ряд с "недаром, не зря". Шишков хотел сказать : не просто так герой думал об Анфисе: он чувствовал, что она думает о нём, здесь речь не о вине, а о общем чувстве. "Бесплатно" я здесь не усматриваю.

Comment: @Людмила а насколько для вас принципиальны именно различия в значениях?  Я понимаю, что они есть, но вот даже если вашт примеры рассматривать, получается, что вы видите два совершенно не связанных между собой значения. При этом объяснения, откуда второе ("бес причины") возникло, нету. Я же смотрю на оба значения как на единое целое, различающееся лишь в деталях - и тогда объяснение возникновения ясно просматривается.  Поэтому я не вижу необходимости в рамках поставленного вопроса противопоставлять современное "даром" и "без причины", которое у М.-С. и Ш.

Comment: Но Вы-то связываете их с виной, а я вины не вижу. Беспричинно, просто так не всегда = даром, бесплатно. Бывает, синонимично, а бывает - и нет.